# problem calling setLocale when creating a new db in android

Tags: android, sqlite, locale

i'm trying some db access code for the first time and i'm getting some errors and would
appreciate some help. this is what is happening:

1) i'm creating a new instance of SQLiteOpenHelper by calling this constructor:

```
public MyDbOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "some_name.db", null, 1); 
}
```

the above instance is the variable myHelper used below

2) i'm calling myHelper.getReadableDatabase()

3) at this point Android calls my onCreate method. my implementation of this method 
begins as follows:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.setLocale(new Locale("en"));
    //...
}
```

4) the above call does not complete. i get the following dump:

BEGIN TRANSACTION  failed setting locale
   couldn't open some_name.db for writing (will try read-only):
   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: cannot start a transaction within a transaction
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_setLocale(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.setLocale(SQLiteDatabase.java:1751)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper...
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper....

it looks like since i'm trying to get a readable db when the db does not yet exist, so Android
tries to create it and creates a writable db for the setLocale... and is that why
it complains about "transaction within transaction"?
how is it supposed to be done?

thanks, any help would be appreciated